# Highly customizable social network platform

Tags: php, customization, social-networking

I'm searching a social network platform, premium or free, that is complete, with good features, but 100% customizable to add my own features, and easy to customize.
I want all social network's features, but i need to add my own code, object, classes and db.
So i would to use php and find a platform with an easy logic structure to handle.

I am a little confused, there are a lot of social network platform: elgg, buddypress, socialengine, but i don't understand if is possible to extend and how is difficult! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elgg is a good solution. Its the award winning social network platform. If you are familiar with MVC architecture, you can add/ extend / convert elgg into anything which you can imagine.

Comment: wow, thx a lot for your reply! i love mvc :)
i hope to start early and have a fun make my social network.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook API is "HUGE". I mean there is no bigger API with more resources available to you in terms of scale, customization, and community support.

It's built in PHP and has several base plugin implimentations you can start out with and build on.

### Your "APP" could be:

- imbedded widget on your independent website that interfaces with facebook through API calls
- installed widget on facebook users platforms.

Comment: I want an indipendent platform that give me to make my modules in easy and powerfull ways. Is elgg good to this purpose?

Comment: I've never heard of them to be honest.